# Java Parameter Passing

Tags: java, class, object, interface, parameter-passing

I am confused about the code below. This code is written by someone else and I am currently studying the code to make more sense of how parameter-passing works in Java.

Does code #1

```
addKeyListener((KeyListener)new TAdapter());
```

and  code #2

```
addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
```

mean the same thing and perform the same thing assuming TAdapter is a class that extends the KeyAdapter class? I also notice I do not necessarily have to explicitly cast the TAdapter object as a KeyListener even though from the method description I read in Eclipse the method takes in a KeyListener object. Why is this possible?
    I did a quick search on the KeyAdapter class from Java docs and apparently the KeyAdapter class implements the KeyListener interface. 
    So am I safe to assume that one of the way Java works in parameter passing is that the method can accept an instance of a class that inherits from a certain class that implements an interface of the same name listed in the method description? If this is so, why is this also possible?

P.S. On a side note, I do not understand why the programmer name the class TAdapter, what does the T stand for? I also notice this type of class naming in other source code, but I never understood this supposed convention.

Comment: I love your side question.  You are right to ask it.  Although I normally go to great lengths not to criticize other programmers, I can say `TAdapter` is a terrible name.  It looks like it is trying to adapt the letter `T` or something.  (Yeah I know it is Hungarian notation for "type", but sheesh!)

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure I never adopt this mysterious T letter into naming my class. I hate picking bad habits.

Comment: OP doesn't understand the concepts of programming, particular Java. Naming conventions is the one of them.

Comment: [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) is what Sun (errm... Oracle) advises us to conform to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes, it is true that "the method can accept an instance of a class that inherits from a certain class that implements an interface".

More generally, a class that `implements` an interface can be said to be a subclass of that interface in terms of polymorphism, and any parameter or variable can be assigned an instance of any subclass of its declared class.

As for why that class is named `TAdapter`, I'm afraid I can't answer. It's not any generally used convention, at least. :)

Comment: Wow! I never knew a class that implements an interface can be a subclass of that interface. So TAdapter is just a random class name? I found it weird that this class name is the same name the second time from my own experience looking at source code.

Comment: Oh I thought interfaces was simply a set of methods that all classes share.

Comment: And the point of sharing all those methods is that you can interchange them in the callers. They don't need to care which of the classes that implement an interface they're using.

Answer (score 1):

If a method takes a **ObjectParameter** as an argument, it can also take **SubClassOfObjectParameter** due to **polymorphism**.

The **T** in at the start of **TAdapter** is just a bad naming style because it is cryptic!

Comment: Oh I see. So polymorphism makes this possible. I will bear in mind about the bad naming style. Thanks Abraham! =]

Answer (score 1):

> So am I safe to assume that one of the way Java works in parameter
>   passing is that the method can accept an instance of a class that
>   inherits from a certain class that implements an interface of the same
>   name listed in the method description?

Yes

> If this is so, why is this also
>   possible?

This is because of polymorphism. You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). Especially the polymorphism subsection.

Comment: I understand polymorphism even more now. Thanks, De Moon.